# A value of type '?' cannot be used as a default parameter | .net 6 vs .net 4.8

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

This piece of code is for `.net core 6` :

```
WebCallResult<AddressInfo> CreateAddress(
    string coin,
    string walletId,
    string label,
    int chain = 0,
    string gasPrice = default,
    bool lowPriority = false,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

I want to use it in `.net framework 4.8`.
In .net framework 4.8 i have this error :

> A value of type '?' cannot be used as a default parameter because
> there are no standard conversions to type 'string'

How can i fix this error?

---

**EDIT :**
Error occurs in this line :

```
string gasPrice = default,
```

Comment: Which part exactly causes this error?

Comment: Which language version are you using? `default` without the target type was introduced in C# 7.1. FWIW, you could use `null` there instead of `default`.

Comment: Please see my edit. I am using visual studio 2015 - .net framework 4.8.

Comment: You could take a hint from the cancellation token argument where the type of the default value is provided. Replace `default` with `default(string) `

Comment: Adding to @madreflection, `default` returns `?` as a null. It's probably `default(string)`.

Comment: Also consider using a more recent version of Visual Studio

Comment: As a side note, at some point, you're going to have to expect that code that works on .NET 6 is just not going to work on .NET Framework. That requires understanding the differences in language and runtime versions and making the necessary changes. Things are changing rapidly, and .NET Framework has been left behind.  Not "is being", *"has been"*. It's done.

Comment: with this trick i have no error : `default(string)` - Please put it as answer. Thank you guys - You are the best.

Comment: @SotirisKoukios-Panopoulos Do you mind elaborate in a answer or it's not necessary?

Comment: Nah go ahead and take it if you'd like, I see we both commented the same thing at the same time.

Comment: Both of you > Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the `gasPrice = default`, you are setting a `default` for a string, which in <C#7.1 has no definition to `default` as a string, that way the value will be `?` for string instead of a accepted value like `null`.

For that specific reason (the runtime version) you have to set the `default(string)`or manually set the value to `null`. References to all default values can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values#:%7E:text=That%20default%20value%20is%20also%20known%20as%20the,variable%20with%20the%20default%20value%20of%20its%20type%3A).